# Is there any difference between the tags "grammaticality" and "grammatically"?

Tags: discussion

The tag description for "grammaticality" says, "Grammaticality refers to whether something obeys the rules of grammar for English." The tag "grammatically" has no description, but its [23 questions](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatically) all seem to be concerned with whether something obeys the rules of English grammar. Four of the questions under this tag follow the format of "Is ________ correct/grammatically correct?" and several others ask which of two options is correct. It seems that all of these questions fit the description of the "grammaticality" tag, so does the "grammatically" tag have some other purpose that sets it apart?

Comment: 'grammatically' sounds like a typo preserved

Comment: Should all the questions with that tag be tagged as "grammaticality" instead? That tag has close to 3,000 questions, so it was definitely there first.

Comment: What @Nicole said. I've done a few (some of which had *both* tags, which seems totally daft to me).

Comment: Well-spotted, I've never noticed the anomaly. Synonym tag should be voted on, asap,before people forget.

Comment: Ahh, only two users have bothered to vote so far. C'mon how much time does this take?

Comment: @Mari-LouA: the system has some rather draconian rules about who is allowed to vote on tag synonyms. Frankly, I'm surprised it allowed me to suggest the synonym at all.

Comment: I tried to vote on it, but I don't have enough rep from that tag, apparently.

Comment: To upvote the synonym one needs to have 2,500 rep and at least 5 points earned by asking or answering any question tagged "grammaticality". There are plenty of users and mods who fit the criteria

Comment: @Mari-LouA: that's to transfer "grammaticality" to "grammatically", which we presumably don't want. The other way round requires users who have rep on "grammatically"; there are only 11 such questions, so it may take some time.

Comment: There are now three votes for the suggested synonym which Martha has posted in her answer.

Comment: @Mari-LouA: 2 days later, and it's still at three votes. I'm not sure if there really are that many people who meet the voting criteria, even though I don't believe Tim is correct about which tag is the significant one. The problem, I think, is with the "5 points", which sounds like "5 rep" — i.e. trivially easy — but actually means "net five upvotes" and isn't very easy at all.

Comment: Oh, I thought it was the equivalent of one upvote on a question. Five points can't mean the same as five upvotes, that's 50 points!? But even so, there are better "qualified" and more experienced users than I who must have earned those points. Tchrist, regdwight, medica, fumblefingers, andrew leach, hellion, john lawler etc.

Comment: @Mari-Lou Perhaps they haven't seen this post, then.

Comment: Perhaps they don't care...

Comment: I just gave the last needed vote, so it's a synonym now :) I would have done so earlier had I been online :)

Comment: Thanks oerkelens!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I have suggested [grammatically](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammatically) as a synonym of [grammaticality](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/grammaticality).  I *believe* that if the synonym is approved, re-tagging becomes unnecessary, but that may just be wishful thinking on my part. In any case, if the system will let you, please [vote](https://english.stackexchange.com/tags/grammaticality/synonyms) on the synonym suggestion.

(It should go without saying that I believe the "grammatically" tag is a typo for "grammaticality".)

*ETA: the synonym is now approved (thanks for the last vote, oerkelens!), and I was right: the system automatically re-tagged all the relevant questions.*

Comment: It seemed like a typo to me, too, but I wondered if 23 different people could make the same typo. Besides, the creation of the tag must have been approved, right?

Comment: @Nicole: if the person who originally created the tag had high enough rep, then no, there was no approval required. Subsequent users of the tag probably started typing "grammat...", at which point both tags came up, and they chose the wrong one -- the two words *look* almost identical. Or, for the ones who used both tags, they decided "well, let's just cover all our bases".

Comment: Another possibility: someone wants to add the (nonexistent) tag "grammatically-correct" to a question. As soon as they get to the hyphen, the possibilities list goes empty, so they backspace until the list comes back up again, and choose the closest (read: only) match, namely [tag:grammatically].

Comment: I retagged a few before I got bored and decided to let others finish the job, but in retrospect yours is a better approach. It turns out I *can* endorse your synonym proposal, but I recall that on other similar occasions in the past I've not been able to do this because I don't happen to have enough rep gained from questions associated with the specific tag involved. Your reasoning as to how 22 people managed to select the "inappropriate" alternative (after one initial mistake) sounds convincing to me; dealing with it your way should mean we'll avoid it cropping up again in future.